# Codeigniter 4 routing error with namespace contains number

Tags: routes, codeigniter-4

I use CodeIgniter 4 latest version.
And i want a route for example Controllers/1_0/Users.php
But if i try use Users.php namespace to app\Controllers\1_0, i receive error. Is have solution or not?
Best regards.

My routes:

```
$routes->get('user/login', "1_0\Users::login");
```

Users.php namespace:

```
namespace app\Controllers\1_0;
```

UPDATE:
I receive this error:

```
"1_0" is not a valid namespace
```

and

```
404-Page not found
```

[errro message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLYyO.png)

Comment: Your question looks very poorly formatted.  This makes it hard to read. Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: In addition,  share with us the specific routing error that you're receiving. Otherwise, no one will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `1_0` as a (sub) namespace in PHP.
CodeIgniter has nothing to do with it.

A valid name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.